# Formed Suction Intake - What is the purpose of splitting it?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pumps

[image]

Some FSI's appear to be split down the middle. Others appear to not have this split. What purpose does this component serve? Is this component ever serving the purpose of a structural support?

[image]

Comment: probably a support rod, not a splitter

Answer (score 1):

These Formed Suction Intakes are used with Vertical pumps and are designed to replace the Submerged sump pumps with stationary vertical pumps. They are regulated by set of codes and standards.

Here is the ANSI/HI 9.8-1998 American National Standard for
Pump Intake Design. [source](http://marineman.ir/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ANSI-HI_9.8.pdf)